# How to show Request data in Summary report and HTML dashboard report in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I want to show the request data which is passed in post API in the Summary report and HTML dashboard report. For Eg. If the Login API is hit then baseURL/api/auth/users/login
Input Data : { "Email" : "abc@gmail.com", "Password" : "Abc123"}
I need to show { "Email" : "abc@gmail.com", "Password" : "Abc123"} this data in summary report and HTML dashboard report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [JMeter 5.4.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-4-1-released-td5739226.html) it's not very possible without massive changes to [JMeter Source code](https://jmeter.apache.org/svnindex.html)

Moreover I doubt the functionality will ever be implemented because you should [reduce resource requirements to the absolute minimum](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean)

If for some reason you still need to have the request data information somewhere in the report the only option I can think of is adding the request data to the [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) label, something like:

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which data you need to store (or if you want to store the data for all Samplers - put the JSR223 PostProcessor at the same level with the Samplers, see [JMeter Scoping Rules - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) for more details)
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   prev.setSampleLabel(prev.getSampleLabel() + ': ' + prev.getSamplerData())
   ```

   [image]

This is what you will get in the [Summary Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report) listener:

[image]

and this is how will [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) look like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitri, As always again you help me to solve the query, This is exactly I wanted in the report. Thank you very much.

Comment: In the same way How can I show the response in the report. Can you please help me.